# Problema com importação do Headers no Angular

Tags: angular

Estava com meu projeto funcionando até um belo dia um fragmento do meu projeto resolveu dá problema de importação e gerou esse erro ao compilar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao fazer uma breve pesquisa na internet encontrei isso como resposta:

[Angular2 - HTTP RequestOptions HEADERS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205570/angular2-http-requestoptions-headers)

Ou seja! as importações abaixo ficaram absoltos, de acordo com essa [documentação](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders)

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
```

E deve ser usado assim:

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Porém quando coloco a nova importação também dá problema, é o mesmo erro.

Eu vi que existe também essa informação

[Http headers don't work](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18325)

Ai eu troquei o módulo de **HttpModule** por **HttpClientModule**

Beleza, fiz a alteração mas ainda continuou com o mesmo erro, e agora?

Preciso de ajuda!

O código que está dando problema é esse:

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Cerveja } from './../core/model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CervejasService {

  cervejasUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/cervejas';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }
    adicionar(cerveja: Cerveja): Promise<Cerveja> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post(this.cervejasUrl,
        JSON.stringify(cerveja),  { HttpHeaders })
      .toPromise()
      .then(response =>  response.json())
      .catch( response => {
        if ( response.status === 400 ) {
            const responseJson = response.json();
            if (responseJson[0].mensagemUsuario === 'O sabor é obrigatório' ) {
              return Promise.reject('O sabor é obrigatório');
            }
            if (responseJson[0].mensagemUsuario === 'O estilo é obrigatório' ) {
              return Promise.reject('O estilo é obrigatório');
            }
            if (responseJson[0].mensagemUsuario === 'A origem é obrigatória' ) {
              return Promise.reject('A origem é obrigatória');
            }
            if ( responseJson[0].mensagemUsuario === 'A comissão é obrigatória' ) {
              return Promise.reject('A comissão é obrigatória');
            }
            if ( responseJson[0].mensagemUsuario === 'A comissão deve ser igual ou menor que 100' ) {
              return Promise.reject('A comissão deve ser igual ou menor que 100');
            }
            if (responseJson[0].mensagemUsuario === 'O teor alcóolico é obrigatório' ) {
              return Promise.reject('O teor alcóolico é obrigatório');
            }
            if (responseJson[0].mensagemUsuario === 'O valor do teor alcóolico deve ser menor que 100' ) {
              return Promise.reject('O valor do teor alcóolico deve ser menor que 100');
            }
            if (responseJson[0].mensagemUsuario === 'Valor é obrigatório' ) {
              return Promise.reject('Valor é obrigatório');
            }
            if (responseJson[0].mensagemUsuario === 'O valor da cerveja deve ser maior que R$0,50' ) {
              return Promise.reject('O valor da cerveja deve ser maior que R$0,50');
            }
            if (responseJson[0].mensagemUsuario === 'O valor da cerveja deve ser menor que R$9.999.999,99' ) {
              return Promise.reject('O valor da cerveja deve ser menor que R$9.999.999,99');
            }
            if (responseJson[0].mensagemUsuario === 'A quantidade em estoque é obrigatória' ) {
              return Promise.reject('A quantidade em estoque é obrigatória');
            }
            if (responseJson[0].mensagemUsuario === 'A quantidade em estoque deve ser menor que 9.999' ) {
              return Promise.reject('A quantidade em estoque deve ser menor que 9.999');
            }
            if (responseJson[0].mensagemUsuario === 'SKU deve seguir o padrão XX9999' ) {
              return Promise.reject('SKU deve seguir o padrão XX9999');
            }
        }
        return Promise.reject (response);
    });
  }

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Na [documentação do angular](https://angular.io/api/http/Headers) o import está correto.

Comment: rodou npm install ou yarn install novamente com a atualizacao da dependencia?

Comment: acabei de roda depois de ter includo as minhas alterações, mas não funcionou.